# Why the first order conditions calculated from EulerEquations is different from the result of manual work?

Tags: differential-equations

[image]
f[x] is a function of x, a and c are constants. If I work out manually, partial derivative of dH[x]/df[x] should be a/f[x] + c*f''[x]/f'[x] = 0, but why here the output [37] seems to drop the term with c? I think the result should contain c.

Comment: Faye, please include your code as text, rather than as an image, so we can copy / paste it in our own notebooks and play with it. Additionally, please make sure that you include definitions for all user-defined variables or functions, if any.

Comment: Your result `a/f[x] + c*f''[x]/f'[x] = 0` is incorrect. It is a generally known fact that the term in the Lagrangian containing the first power of the derivative makes no contribution to the Euler equation. The result returned by Mma is right.

Comment: Try using `EulerEquations[a Log[f[x]] + g[x] f'[x], f[x], x]`. The term with `c` drops out because it is a constant.